# Cant login Script even if i have user and password set on my Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have purchase the script "Jqcm - Premium Responsive Quiz Engine" script.
Now, the author disappear and dont answer for questions for months.

When i try to login to the backend with my user + password i get a circled bar for 1 second and it isnt go inside the backend and stays on the login auth page.

See for yourself: http://coreneto.com/jcqm/backend/#/authentication

user: user_admin
pass: user_admin

The DB is connect and credentials are correct and set.

Here yhe code under index.html at backend folder:

```
<!doctype html> <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/2dae0413.vendor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/b353aa04.main.css">

<body ng-app="jqcmBackendApp" ng-cloak="" class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-if="config.loading" id="spinner" style="position:fixed;top: 50%;left: 50%;z-index:99"></div>
    <div growl=""></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">
                You are using an <strong>outdated</strong>
                browser. Please
                <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a>
                to improve your experience.
            </p>
            <![endif]-->
    <div ng-if="config.user" ng-controller="MenuCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jqcm Panel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li ng-if="config.user.role==='ADMIN' || config.user.role==='EDITOR'"><a href="#/subjects">Subjects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-if="config.user.role==='ADMIN' || config.user.role==='EDITOR'"><a href="#/tests">Tests</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-if="config.user.role==='ADMIN'"><a href="#/users">Users</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#/users/{{config.user.uuid}}">My Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><a style="cursor: pointer" ng-confirm-action="" confirmed-action="Logout()">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/baa800ef.vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/c6a59f06.scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/configuration.js"></script>

</body>
```

Error log say:

```
[06-Aug-2015 04:56:26 GMT] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php on line 29
[06-Aug-2015 04:56:26 GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php(29): Slim\LogWriter->__construct(false)
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php on line 60
[06-Aug-2015 04:56:29 GMT] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php on line 29
[06-Aug-2015 04:56:29 GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php(29): Slim\LogWriter->__construct(false)
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php on line 60
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: add codes related to your use loging

Comment: Warning: fopen(/home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php on line 29

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php:60Stack trace:#0 /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php(29): Slim\LogWriter->__construct(false)#1 {main} thrown in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php on line 60

Comment: the issue is you dont have permession to login directly you have set the cors or setting with jcqm

Comment: Ahmer, what exactly do i need to do for it to login? (i own the server and have all credentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file in path `jcqm/api/log.txt`and set permission to `0666` to it.

The following warning message found in `console.log`

> Warning: fopen(/home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php on line 29
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/index.php(29): Slim\LogWriter->__construct(false) #1 {main} thrown in /home/coreneto/public_html/jcqm/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/LogWriter.php on line 60

Comment: Ok. Did it. What next?